# Reference to existing related entity in YAML file

Tags: symfony, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I'm setting a YAML file for an entity, and there are some related fields that are already populated in database, so I want to reference those values in the current YAML file.

For example, `status` field in next sample should load an `App\Entity\Status` that already exists in database (1 to 3 are existing IDs, but it fails):

```
App\Entity\Dummy:
    dummy_{1..10}:
        name: '<firstName()>'
        surnames: '<lastName()>'
        email (unique): '<email()>'
        startDate: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
        subject: '<sentence()>'
        status: '<numberBetween(1, 3)>'
```

When loading this file with `--append` option, I get this error:

> Invalid value given for the property "status" of the object "dummy_1" (class: App\Entity\Dummy)

> Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\Status", "int" given at property path "status".

How can I reference a pre-existing entity?

About the "related" question, in that question the related entity is loaded in a separate YAML file (not my case, the related entity is already in database), and that question does not have an answer.

Comment: Also, where can I find a complete reference to functions like `<firstName()>, <lastName()>, <sentence()>` etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from [the docs](https://github.com/nelmio/alice/blob/main/doc/relations-handling.md):

```yaml
Nelmio\Entity\Group:
    group1:
        owner: '@user<numberBetween(1, 200)>'
```

In your case, it would be:

```yaml
App\Entity\Status:
   status_1
       name: "Foo"
   status_2
       name: "Bar"
   status_3
       name: "Baz"


App\Entity\Dummy:
    dummy_{1..10}:
        name: '<firstName()>'
        surnames: '<lastName()>'
        email (unique): '<email()>'
        startDate: '<dateTimeBetween("-200 days", "now")>'
        subject: '<sentence()>'
        status: '@status_<numberBetween(1, 3)>'
```

For pre-existing data, not coming from a fixture... you'll have more difficulties. I'd personally set up everything with the fixtures, which is their purpose. Saving on a few DB transactions is not worth the effort and the uncertainty.

Check [this issue](https://github.com/nelmio/alice/issues/598) for more info and approaches.

Comment: But the **@** is a reference to another fixture, when you set `owner: '@user<numberBetween(1, 200)>'`, a `user` section exists in the same yaml file (or separate fixture). Note that those samples always have an `User` section before the group.

Comment: This is the error returned: *Could not find the fixture "status2"*

Comment: It's a possibility, indeed. But the `status` entity is related to other entities not related to fixture, so, this would force me to delete all statuses in every fixture reload, and to delete all statuses I'll need to delete all other related data, that's why I wanted to use existing values in DB. I'll try that if I don't find another solution.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the proposed solution, if I create a fixture for `Status` entity I'll need to delete it in every fixture reload.

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go if you are using fixtures.